# Sum of number of vertices in a graph

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

### Question

> Let $T$ be a tree on $100$ vertices. Let $n_{i}$ be the number of vertices in $T$ which have exactly $i$ neighbors. Let $$s= \sum_{i=1}^{100}\,\, i . n_i$$ Which of the following is true?

$A)s=99$

$B)s=198$

$C)99 \: < \: s \: < \: 198$

$D)$None of the above

### My Approach

Making it simple, I assumed it as **skewed** tree.So every vertex other than leaf will have exactly $1$ neighbour and only leaf node($100^{th}$vertex) will be having $0$ vertex.

> $$s=\sum_{i=1}^{100}\,\, i . n_{i}$$
>
> $$s=1*1+2*1+3*1+....99*1+100*0$$
>
> $$s=4950$$

So it should be none of these.

Am I right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. In a skewed tree there are $98$ vertices with two neighbors, and two vertices with $1$ neighbor. Then $n_1=2$ and $n_2=98$, and $n_i=0$ for $i\ge 3$.
$$s=1\cdot 2+2\cdot 98=198$$

In fact, a tree with $n$ vertices has $n-1$ edges, and you can think $s$ as the counting of edges of the tree, but each edge is counted as many times as vertices has the edge, that is, twice.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Try to think about your sum in terms of edges; how many times is each edge counted?  For a spoiler, check out [this lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handshaking_lemma).